Opening MS Office URI getting not allowed due to Restricted Site
I am trying to use a MS Office URI which will automatically open Excel 2016. I am using a URI similar to:
ms-excel:ofe|u|<https://localhost:7068/getOfficeFile?fileName=2021_12_06_Metrics.xlsx>

I have also used:
ms-excel:ofe|u|<https://testsite.com/getOfficeFile?fileName=2021_12_06_Metrics.xlsx>

I have created an endpoint in my application to fetch the document and stream it to excel.
It doesn't matter if I run it locally or hosted, when I put the URI into the browser, and hit enter, I get asked if I want to open excel. I say yes, but I always get the same result from Office:
To protect you from unsafe content, Office has blocked opening this file because it is coming from a site in the Restricted Sites zone.

I have tried adding mysite.com to the Trusted locations for Excel and also I've added it to Windows Internet Properties Trusted Sites. I have verified these are not in the Restricted Sites on Windows.
I can't seem to find anything else that would be blocking me from opening this excel file directly in Excel. I can download and open the file just fine, but I want the generated link to automatically open Excel.
Has anyone been able to locate some other Restricted Sites zone?
Has anyone been able to get this to work?

Just trust the location like it says here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/general-development/how-to-trust-a-location
